# CXF Web service proxy configuration issues in Mule

Tags: soap, cxf, mule

Right now, I have a service called ProcessPayment that calls a billing system. As we can see here, I want to make a call to another billing service from my payment service. The response from PaymentService has 3 data elements. One of them is required in BillingService.

How do I configure the flow for two or more services in Mule? I have tried various permutations but it just does not work!

**Mule-config.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:ognl="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ognl" xmlns:servlet="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/servlet"
    xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns:pattern="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.1/mule.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern/3.1/mule-pattern.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ognl http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ognl/current/mule-ognl.xsd 
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd">

    <!-- <flow name="parallelservices"> <all enableCorrelation="ALWAYS"> <cxf:proxy-service 
        wsdlLocation="classpath:billingservice.wsdl" bindingId="BillingServiceServiceSoapBinding" 
        port="BillingServicePort" service="BillingServiceService" payload="body" 
        namespace="http://com.myapp.demo/" /> </all> </flow> -->

    <flow name="initpayment">
        <inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8585/services/processpayment">
            <cxf:proxy-service wsdlLocation="classpath:processpaymentservice.wsdl"
                bindingId="ProcessPaymentServiceServiceSoapBinding" service="ProcessPaymentServiceService"
                payload="body" namespace="http://com.myapp.demo/" />
        </inbound-endpoint>
        <outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8081/BillingEntry/services/BillingServicePort">
            <!-- <flow-ref name="parallelservices" /> -->
            <cxf:proxy-client/>
        </outbound-endpoint>
    </flow>

</mule>
```

**Process Payment wsdl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="ProcessPaymentServiceService" targetNamespace="http://processpayment.icp.sf/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://com.myapp.demo/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<import namespace="http://processpayment.icp.sf/" schemaLocation="processpaymentservice_schema1.xsd"/>
</schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="processPayment">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:processPayment">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="processPaymentResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:processPaymentResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="IProcessPayment">
    <wsdl:operation name="processPayment">
      <wsdl:input name="processPayment" message="tns:processPayment">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="processPaymentResponse" message="tns:processPaymentResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="ProcessPaymentServiceServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:IProcessPayment">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="processPayment">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="processPayment">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="processPaymentResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ProcessPaymentServiceService">
    <wsdl:port name="ProcessPaymentServicePort" binding="tns:ProcessPaymentServiceServiceSoapBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8081/ProcessPayment/services/ProcessPaymentServicePort"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**Billing Service wsdl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="BillingServiceService" targetNamespace="http://com.myapp.demo2/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://billing.icp.sf/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<import namespace="http://billing.icp.sf/" schemaLocation="billingservice_schema1.xsd"/>
</schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="billingEntryResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:billingEntryResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="billingEntry">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:billingEntry">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="IBillingService">
    <wsdl:operation name="billingEntry">
      <wsdl:input name="billingEntry" message="tns:billingEntry">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="billingEntryResponse" message="tns:billingEntryResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="BillingServiceServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:IBillingService">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="billingEntry">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="billingEntry">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="billingEntryResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="BillingServiceService">
    <wsdl:port name="BillingServicePort" binding="tns:BillingServiceServiceSoapBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8081/BillingEntry/services/BillingServicePort"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**Immediate Problems**

I am able to generate the wsdl for ProcessPayment service when I hit the Mule config inbound URL. But it is showing modified values for

```
   <import schemaLocation="".../>
```

and

```
   <wsdl:port><soap:address>*****</soap:address></wsdl:port>
```

Using this URL, I am not able to test the service on SOAPui. But when I hit the service original address, and not the Mule inbound address, I get my actual service. It s running in SOAP UI too.

**Quick question:**

How do I execute a flow? Simply invoking the inbound URL from the browser or SOAPui won't work right?

Comment: If the proxy is working, you should be able to invoke it with soapUI (not a browser though).

Comment: I still don't get what you're trying to do. This clearly doesn't sound like a use case for a proxy because the inbound and outbound services are different. So you want to host ProcessPaymentService in Mule and have the result of this service sent to some method of BillingService? But what would be the result of ProcessPaymentService for the caller of it? Shouldn't the service class of ProcessPaymentService be the one calling BillingService?

Comment: So we use a proxy only when a the inbound and outbound endpoint are same? Actually, I have one service, and from that, the flow will go to three services (that is for later). Right now, I am not able to get one service to call another service in sequence. So, I thought of trying out this scenario first.

Comment: Firstly, should I use a cxf:proxy-service or a cxf:jaxws-service or a cxf:jaxws-client in my flow. Am I right in using a proxy-service? From what I understand, a cxf:proxy-client will take in raw XML payloads. So I was sending the response to the outbound endpoint which has a proxy-client, and before that, I thought of modifying the xml payload through splitters/filters and xpath. Is this approach correct?
The response from process payment has a billing ID field which in required in BillingService. The rest of the fields, I will filter. Is this approach correct?

Comment: Now that I am confused, one simple question. Can I have more than one SOAP services (client or service o proxy) in one flow?
I am using Mule ESB only for orchestration. My services are deployed remotely on a tcServer.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to have several clients in a flow. For service, only one should be used: it doesn't make sense to have more as you are *exposing* only one service per flow. Otherwise your idea of chaining calls with payload transformations in between sounds excellent.

Comment: Do you mind sharing billingservice_schema1.xsd? I'd like to try building a prototype.

Comment: I moved this to chat, and sent you a public link of the mule project and the services (on Dropbox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go, I have created an example that demonstrates how to perform SOAP envelope level manipulations with CXF proxies. From there I'm sure you can expand and build whatever you need.

Please note that:

- No code generation is needed, I actually had to remove the classes you've generated otherwise it is not working. This single XML configuration with the WSDLs+XSDs is enough.
- I've qualified Mule core elements in order to avoid elements XSL-T generated in the default namespace to end up in Mule core namespace. This is not required if you externalize the XSL fragments.
- The (contrived) example exposes processpaymentservice.wsdl. It takes the value of paymentType_req, pretends it's an IP address and uses it to call http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx. The geolocated coutry name is then used as the value for the paymentType_res element of the process payment response (the other 2 values are faked).
- Tested with soapUI 4.5 and Mule 3.2.1.

Enjoy!

```
<mule:flow name="processPaymentServiceOrchestration">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/ppso"
        exchange-pattern="request-response">
        <cxf:proxy-service wsdlLocation="classpath:processpaymentservice.wsdl"
            service="ProcessPaymentServiceService" namespace="http://processpayment.icp.sf/" />
    </http:inbound-endpoint>

    <!-- Transform input of ProcessPayment to input of GetGeoIP -->
    <mulexml:xslt-transformer>
        <mulexml:xslt-text>
            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
              xmlns:web="http://www.webservicex.net/">
              <xsl:template match="/">
                <web:GetGeoIP>
                   <web:IPAddress><xsl:value-of select="//paymentType_req" /></web:IPAddress>
                </web:GetGeoIP>
              </xsl:template>
            </xsl:stylesheet>
        </mulexml:xslt-text>
    </mulexml:xslt-transformer>

    <mule:message-properties-transformer>
        <mule:add-message-property key="SOAPAction" value="http://www.webservicex.net/GetGeoIP" />
    </mule:message-properties-transformer>

    <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx"
        exchange-pattern="request-response">
        <cxf:proxy-client soapVersion="1.2" />
    </http:outbound-endpoint>

    <!-- Transform response of GetGeoIP in response of ProcessPayment -->
    <mulexml:xslt-transformer>
        <mulexml:xslt-text>
            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
              xmlns:pp="http://processpayment.icp.sf/" xmlns:web="http://www.webservicex.net/">
              <xsl:template match="/">
                <pp:return>
                   <billingID_res>fake billingID_res</billingID_res>
                   <paymentID_res>fake paymentID_res</paymentID_res>
                   <paymentType_res><xsl:value-of select="//web:CountryName"/></paymentType_res>
                </pp:return>
              </xsl:template>
            </xsl:stylesheet>
        </mulexml:xslt-text>
    </mulexml:xslt-transformer>
</mule:flow>
```

Comment: I am facing a weird problem. It is working fine in SOAP UI 4.5, but not in SOAP UI 4.0. Wondering what the reason is.
Anyway, thanks. It makes sense now. I have a question. Is there a guide on best practices for designing Mule flows?

Comment: Another thing. What exactly is the purpose of this block?

<mule:message-properties-transformer>
        <mule:add-message-property key="SOAPAction" value="http://www.webservicex.net/GetGeoIP" />
    </mule:message-properties-transformer>

Comment: 1) I don't know of a best practice guide. 2) The SOAPAction header is needed by webservicex.net, it's maybe not the case for your services so it's not mandatory.

Comment: There is a problem now. I just noticed that the Payment service is not getting called!

Comment: There is a problem now. I just noticed that the Payment service is not getting called! What I want is multiple service calls in sequence, using flows. The response from the previous service is the request for the next service.

Comment: I don't get it. Payment service is *exposed* by Mule as an orchestration of other services. Isn't that what you wanted? If it is not what you wanted, then what is it you want? [edit] Just saw you opened a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169593/configuring-flows-in-mule-esb-for-multiple-service-calls